# DataFrame has no attribute to str problem

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

[Here is my csv file in case you need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85JzJ.png)

I am trying to run through every MLB team's playoff appearances and record them, however `"DataFrame" has not attribute to "str"` keeps popping up. Here is my code:

```
record_dict = {}
file=open("playoff_teams.csv", mode="r")
for line in file.readlines():
    split_line = line.split()
    record_dict[split_line[0]]=split_line[1:]
df_playoffs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(record_dict, orient='index' )

list(sorted(set(df_pitching.team))) == list(sorted(set(df_batting.team))) == list(sorted(set(df_playoffs.index)))

df_all = df_pitching.merge(df_batting, on=['year','team'], 
how='left', suffixes=('_pitching', '_batting'))

playoff_appearance = []
for i in range(1969, 2019):                                                                      
    df = df_all[df_all.year == i]

    for team in df.team:
        df_plyoff = df_playoffs[df_playoffs.index == team]

        if df_plyoff.str.contains(str(i))[0]:
            playoff_appearance.append(1)   
        else:
            playoff_appearance.append(0)

world_series = []
for i in range(1969, 2019):
    df = df_all[df_all.year == i]

    for team in df.team:
        df_ws = df_playoffs[df_playoffs.index == team]

        if df_ws.world_series.str.contains(str(i))[0]:  
            world_series.append(1)  
        else:
            world_series.append(0)
```

Here is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/Baseball.py", line 148, in <module>
    if df_plyoff.str.contains(str(i))[0]:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: Your error line `if df_plyoff.str.contains(str(i))[0]:` fails because `df_plyoff` is a `df`, what are you trying to filter exactly? Do you want `if df_plyoff['yeay'].str.contains(str(i))[0]:` Also looping should be avoided at all costs, it's non-performant. What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: The error tells you half of the problem: A dataframe has no `.str` attribute. A _Series_ object has a `.str` attribute. You can operate on all the strings in a column this way, but not the whole dataframe.

Comment: @EdChum im trying to loop through years 1970-2018 and keep track of which teams made it to the playoffs certain years and which teams did not

Answer (score 1):

You have to acquire the corresponding column first before trying to get access to the value of that cell. That line causing the issue should be changed to:

```
if df_plyoff[0].str.contains(str(i)):
```

I am assuming that the column containing the years has no assigned name so defaulted to `0`. Let me know if it does.

Comment: This is the error i get when I change it to that:   ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @Hannah Can you show the output from `df_plyoff[0]`?

Comment: Series([], Name: 0, dtype: object)

Comment: @Hannah ok, what is the column label for the one containing the years? that is what matters. Show the output of `df_plyoff.columns` then.

Comment: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=24, step=1)

Comment: @Hannah you still haven't said what is the column label for the one containing the years?

Comment: I don't have a column label for that.